# How to change dateFormat and timeFormat in FormHelper->dateTime on CakePHP 4.x?

Tags: datetime, time, cakephp-4.x

This is my code located inside a Template. The dateTime control its displaying the dateFormat 'M-D-Y' and timeFormat '12' (AM/PM). I need to change it to the dateFormat 'D-M-Y' and timeFormat '24'.

I searched for the options in [4.x](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-date-time-related-controls) but can't find anything useful. In older versions ([2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#datetime-options) and [3.9](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#datetime-options)) I was able to use

`FormHelper::dateTime($fieldName, $dateFormat = 'DMY', $timeFormat = '12', $attributes = array())`

but now it's

`Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::dateTime($fieldName, $options = [])`.

I've tried using 'dateFormat' and 'timeFormat' inside the options array with no success.

```
<?= $this->Form->dateTime('from', ['default' => true]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->dateTime('from', 'DMY', '24', ['default' => true]); ?> //not working
<?= $this->Form->dateTime('from', ['default' => true, 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'timeFormat' => 24]); ?> //doesn't modify dateFormat or timeFormat
<?= $this->Form->dateTime('from', ['default' => true, 'date_format' => 'DMY', 'time_format' => 24]); ?> //doesn't modify dateFormat or timeFormat
```

This is the config of the app.php

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'es_AR'),
'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormHelper::dateTime()` creates input elements of the type `datetime-local`, you cannot control the display format of these input types (in case supported by the browser in the first place), this is handled by the browser and depends on the user's Browser/OS locale config.

- **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local**
- **https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#input-author-notes**
- **https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#input-impl-notes**

If you need more control over the display format, use a `text` input instead, and a JavaScript based datetime picker that allows you to configure the display format.

Comment: According to this: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#setting-the-default-locale
"The default locale will control several aspects of the application, including the default translations language, the date format, number format and currency whenever any of those is displayed using the localization libraries that CakePHP provides"